# tsconfig path not working in my react typescript project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, babeljs, tsconfig

I search for ten times in google but i cant fix it , i wrote my tsconfig.json and jsconfig for vscode in react typescript project but i have this error when i want start project  , i used module resolver in my .babelrc  before but i had sampe issue 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gh4r1.png)

this is my tsconfig.json in root project

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@Components/*": ["Components/*"],
      "@Redux/*": ["Redux/*"],
      "@Pages/*": ["Pages/*"],
      "@Route/*": ["Route/*"],
      "@Helper/*": ["Helper/*"],
      "@Types/*": ["Types/*"],
      "@Config/*": ["Config/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "build"]
}
```

and its jsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@Components/*": ["Components/*"],
      "@Redux/*": ["Redux/*"],
      "@Pages/*": ["Pages/*"],
      "@Route/*": ["Route/*"],
      "@Helper/*": ["Helper/*"],
      "@Types/*": ["Types/*"],
      "@Config/*": ["Config/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

and my structure is

Root 
  src
    Components
    Redux
  .babelrc
  tsconfig.json
  jsconfig.json

Comment: It seems that you are trying to use aliases (`paths`) in scss file. Scss is not connected with js or ts so these aliases do not work there. You can find more about sass imports in [official doc](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import)

Comment: it means that main problem is for scss files ?

Comment: Please read the error you posted. It shows the exact place of error at the very beginning, and I explained the reason for it in my first comment.